# Setting the title of the AppBar

Tags: android

As I'm currently working on an app with parse I want to have a list of users and if you tap on one of their names a new activity is launched with their profile. When the a activity is launched the objectId of the parse object is sent to the activity with the intent. Here is my problem: I want the title of the activity to be the username. I found a solution but it's somewhat strange. Maybe someone has a better solution?

Here is my code(which works fine but I have to set the title twice otherwise it doesn't work):

```html
public class UserProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String userId;
    String username;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);
        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

        userId = getIntent().getStringExtra("userId");

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("objectId", userId);
        query.setLimit(1);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    if (objects.size() != 0) {
                        for (ParseUser user : objects) {
                            Log.i("AppInfo", user.getUsername());
                            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(user.getUsername());
                            username = user.getUsername();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(username);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an issue in this code?

Comment: I am wondering why I have to set the title two times to make it show up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to set it twice.

The `username` will be available inside the done method when the query completes. The `setTitle` line outside the loop will not work. Remove the `setTitle` after the `findInBackground`.

See this code.

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
query.whereEqualTo("objectId", userId);
query.setLimit(1);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            if (objects.size() != 0) {
                for (ParseUser user : objects) {
                    Log.i("AppInfo", user.getUsername());
                    username = user.getUsername();
                    // adding some null checks
                    if(null != getSupportActionBar() && username != null && !username.equals("")){
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(username);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

getSupportActionBar().setTitle(username);  // remove this line
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work unfortunately. If I do it like this it'll just show the default activity title.

Comment: Nevermind it works after I restarted the emulator. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are using an `async` call of `parse`. And when that call is made, the next line (that is setting the `title`) is run instantly. At that time the `username` variable contains `null`.

And in the done callback of the parse query, you are setting the title again. Actually this is the actual line that is doing work for you.

```
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    if (objects.size() != 0) {
                        for (ParseUser user : objects) {
                            Log.i("AppInfo", user.getUsername());
                            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(user.getUsername());
                            username = user.getUsername();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

You can remove this line `getSupportActionBar().setTitle(username);` after the call and the code will work same but it will set the tile with just setting the title once.